# How to Inject 2 EventHubClient from StartUp in .NetCore 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-eventhub

I am injecting EventHubClient in my Controller like below

```
services.AddScoped<EventHubClient>(a =>
     {
        eventHubClientIncomplete = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(new EventHubsConnectionStringBuilder(eventHubSettingsIncompleteApplications.ConnectionString)
        {
           EntityPath = eventHubSettingsIncompleteApplications.EventHubName
        }.ToString());
        return eventHubClientIncomplete;
     });
```

It's working fine. But now i have a requirement to send to multiple EventHubs from different endpoints.. How do i do that...any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of 3 solutions：

1.Create your own factory for `EventHubClient`. Then add the factory in services. In this way you will be able to inject the factory instance when needed, and then get wanted `EventHubClient` from factory method.

2.Use other DI engine. For example: Unity Container, with which you can get service as following: `container.Resolve<IService>(key)`

3.Create a class for holding `EventHubClient`.

```
    public class EventHubClientHolder
    {
        public string Name;
        public EventHubClient eventHubClient;
    }
```

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSingleton<EventHubClientHolder>(_ => { return new EventHubClientHolder() { Name = "A", eventHubClient = ..... }; });
        services.AddSingleton<EventHubClientHolder>(_ => { return new EventHubClientHolder() { Name = "B", eventHubClient = ..... }; });
    }
```

```
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IEnumerable<EventHubClientHolder> services)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _services = services;
    }
```

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var eventHubClient = _services.First(_ => _.Name.Equals("A"))).eventHubClient;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jack..I will try out these ...apologies couldn't reply earlier.